# Can Mann Whitney U test be used for uneven sample sizes?

Tags: wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

N1=240
N2=260

Also a reference to your answer would be great please!

Comment: The first duplicate (which was in *Related* in the sidebar and should have been offered to you as a possible answer when you were trying to post) directly responds to your question and includes a reference in comments

Answer (score 1):

Yes. See: [original paper by Mann and Whitney](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aoms/1177730491).

Specifically, note the last sentence in their abstract referring to two distinct sample sizes.

> Let $x$ and $y$ be two random variables with continuous cumulative
>   distribution functions $f$ and $g$. A statistic $U$ depending on the
>   relative ranks of the $x$'s and $y$'s is proposed for testing the
>   hypothesis $f=g$. Wilcoxon proposed an equivalent test in the Biometrics
>   Bulletin, December, 1945, but gave only a few points of the
>   distribution of his statistic. Under the hypothesis $f=g$ the
>   probability of obtaining a given $U$ in a sample of $n$ $x$'s and $m$ $y$'s is the
>   solution of a certain recurrence relation involving $n$ and $m$. [...]